# Append form action with input variable

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form whose action is

```
<form action="/food/vegetable" method="POST" >
```

My controller method takes vegetable name as parameter

I would like to append the input vegetable name to the action. 
for example

```
<form action="/food/vegetable/{vegetableName}" method="POST" >
```

Is it possible to do this ? or is there a better way ? Please guide.

Comment: Sure you can do it like that. A suggestion though, check out "named routes" in the  [Laravel Documentation](https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#named-routes)

Comment: Highly recommend Named Routes as well. This adds a layer of abstraction to the routing pattern, so if you change it's end point, you only have to change it one place.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're sending data with POST method, put this hidden field into your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="vegetableName" value="{{ $vegetableName }}">
```

Then you can get this data in a controller:

```
$vegetableName = $request->vegetableName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery submit event.

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var veg = $("#INPUTBOX_ID").val();
  location.href = "/food/vegetable"+veg;
```

});

you could process value of veg however you want.

Answer (score 0):

give your form an ID and then in JS you can write the code below.

If you receive the vegetable param as a parameter in the url of the form (ex. path/to/form?vegetable=carrot) you can use the following function to get the name of the param

```js
function getParameterByName(name) {
  url = window.location.href;
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
  var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
      results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results) return null;
  if (!results[2]) return '';
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
var vegetable = getParameterByName("vegetable");
document.getElementById("myForm").action = "/food/vegetable/"+vegetable;
```

```html
<form id="myForm" action="/food/vegetable/{vegetableName}" method="POST" >
</form>
```